# Can my Anagram Program Run? If yes, why is it not compiling?

Tags: c, string, anagram

my program does not compile. It keeps on saying:
[ERROR] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*'
It should be a program that identifies if two strings are an anagram of each other.
I used a sorting method but i don't know if it will work. 
Hope you guys could help me out.
P.S I can only use strings and arrays.

```
int main ()
{
    char sString_1[100], sString2[100], store[50];
    int  j, i;

    printf("Enter String 1: ");
    gets(sString_1);
    printf("\nEnter String 2: ");
    gets(sString2);

    if (strlen(sString_1) != strlen(sString2))
        printf("%s and %s are not anagrams", sString_1, sString2);
    else
    {
        for(i = 0; i < strlen(sString_1); ++i)
        {
            for (j=i+1 ; j <= strlen(sString_1); ++j)
            {
                if (strcmp(sString_1[i], sString2[j]) > 0)
                {
                    strcpy(store,sString_1[i]);
                    strcpy(sString_1[i],sString_1[j]);
                    strcpy(sString_1[j],store);
                }

            }
        }

        for(i = 0; i < strlen(sString2); i++)
        {
            for (j= i + 1; j <= strlen(sString2); j++)
            {
                if (strcmp(sString2[i], sString2[j]) >0)
                {
                    strcpy(store,sString2[i]);
                    strcpy(sString2[i],sString2[j]);
                    strcpy(sString2[j],store);
                }
            }
        }

        if (strcmp(sString_1, sString2) == 0)
            printf("ANAGRAM");
        else
            printf("NOT");
    }
}
```

Comment: on which line of code? Please remove all and keep [MCVE]

Comment: This whole program is written with C functions. If you _are_ using C++, do try to use the inbuilt string class - they make life easier, in my experience.

Comment: Look at `strcpy(store,sString_1[i]);`.  What are the two things you are using and what are the parmeter types of `strcpy`?

Comment: Where's the c++ stuff?

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp(sString_1[i], sString2[j])`

The arguments to strcmp shoud be of type `const char *`, yet you pass single chars.

Comment: And for `strcpy` as well.

Answer (score 0):

In general when you use `p[i]` then you are changing the pointer (or array) `p` into what it points to, e.g. a character.
It is like writing `*(p+i)`. To get the address of that character you can either write `p+i` or `&p[i]`.

Example: to fix the errors you have to change

```
strcmp(sString_1[i], sString2[j])
```

into

```
strcmp(&sString_1[i], &sString2[j])
```

Comment: thankyou for that. But now i'm having trouble with this lines:

Comment: if (strcmp(sString_1, sString2) == 0)
        printf("ANAGRAM");
    else
        printf("NOT");

Comment: Look at your two strcmp's: the first one compares 1 and 2, the second 2 and 2.

Comment: But i dont understand you anagram algorithm. What I would do is this: sort both strings. E.g. 'dog' becomes 'dgo', 'god' also becomes 'dgo' so you can just strcmp them after sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to make like this?

```
    char sString_1[100], sString2[100], store;            // store is 1char
//=======omit==========
    else
    {
        for(i = 0; i < strlen(sString_1); ++i)
        {
            for (j=i+1 ; j < strlen(sString_1); ++j)         // "<="→"<"
            {
                if (sString_1[i] > sString2[j])              // char
                {
                    store = sString_1[i];                    // char
                    sString_1[i] = sString_1[j];
                    sString_1[j] = store;
                }
            }
        }
        for(i = 0; i < strlen(sString2); i++)
        {
            for (j= i + 1; j < strlen(sString2); j++)         // "<="→"<"
            {
                if (sString2[i] > sString2[j])                // char
                {
                    store = sString2[i];                      // char
                    sString2[i] = sString2[j];
                    sString2[j] = store;
                }
            }
        }
//=======omit==========
```

1 loop
4250
2450
0452
2 loop
0254
3 loop
0245